# Webcam disconnects/crashes once per session after ~5 minutes

Tags: webcam, logitech, disconnect

Ubuntu 18.04

Kernel 4.15.0-34-generic

Standard Gnome+Xorg

Logitech HD Pro C920

I have this issue in both Google Hangouts and Google Meet, in both Chrome and Firefox. Consistently, once per call, my camera disconnects and stops showing as an available device. I have to unplug and reconnect it, which works but for the 5 seconds it takes to detect after plugging in everything locks up, including audio output. I tried doing it pre-emptively right before a call but that had no effect.

If it's helpful, I used this same camera on the same machine running Arch for a few months prior to this and never saw this problem.

Two other notes -- I connect the camera via a usb-c adapter which also has an ethernet port and noticed my ethernet connection also resets (at least the icon in the top right does). I also tried connecting it through a single usb-c to usb-3.1 adapter (no ethernet) and had the same disconnect issue.

`journalctl` output: https://pastebin.com/raw/EpjJtBpL

Comment: Also tried leaving Cheese and guvcview open for ~30 min each and don't see this issue.

Comment: In a terminal window, execute `journalctl --follow`. When the camera disconnects look at the log messages.

Comment: I attached the output to the question. Sorry it's a bit noisy with things like Discord but I didn't want to strip anything in case it mattered.

Comment: It's not "logvomit". It's the log you asked for, starting immediately when it crashed and ending a few seconds later. If I knew what to look for in there I wouldn't be here. You also are under no obligation to comment on my question, so if it seems like too much work don't bother.

Comment: FWIW my guess based on those logs is that it suddenly thinks it's a keyboard instead of a webcam, but I've never seen a similar problem before and it appears to be more OS/kernel-specific than hardware or website specific.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking into this for a while - also have C920, and it works well except periodically disconnecting while I'm in a meeting. There are a lot of similar reports on a lot of different forums.

The most likely-seeming answer I've come across so far is in [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=40551), which suggests that the camera is momentarily drawing more power than the PC can respond with (or perhaps than can quickly be provided via the USB adapter or hub). Responses on that thread end (/ the thread is marked SOLVED) after the user gets a powered USB hub to ensure clean / consistent power to the C920. Some comments in the thread note that lowering the resolution in-meeting may also reduce the power draw, at least for some USB cameras.

Don't know if this will be a solution, but I won't be able to test / verify myself for a couple of weeks and so want to drop this note in case.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I no longer have this computer or webcam to check, but it's a good thing to try in the future.